# Identify Component on RPI-4B Bottom (SD card Controller?)

Tags: pi-4

There's little PCB component docs available for RPI-4B. I believe I need to replace the circled component shown. Please identify and if possible provide the code identifier for this component so I can search for it.

Thank You

[image: RPI-4B Bottom Component]

Comment: if you don't know what it is, then what leads you to believe that you need to replace it?

Comment: It's hot. Can you identify it?

Comment: you already asked that question ... this site is not a forum ... you don't have to repeat a question

Comment: what are the markings on it?

Comment: You can remove this question.